# How to save the brush event when hovering over elements with their own events

Tags: javascript, d3.js, events, mouseevent, brush

I have a brush overlay that tracks zoom events. it is stretched over the entire graph area and is drawn first, and then the graph lines. This is done so that I can process click events, mouseover, mouseout separately, for example, to highlight the graph. At the same time, I want to maintain the ability to zoom while being above the graph line, but my brush is lost, how can I fix this?

I thought about sending the event to the overlay using dispatchEvent, but I don’t understand how to create brush events.
Or maybe you need to somehow reactivate the brush?